# Inheriting methods from a superclass with Python dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a couple of dataclasses where I want to modify the comparison methods. I implemented this class:

```py
@dataclass
class ComparisonMixin:
    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        result = True
        for s, o in zip(self, __o):
            if isinstance(s, datetime.datetime) and isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
                margin = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
                result = result and s - margin <= o <= s + margin
            elif o:
                result = result and s == o
        return result

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[datetime.datetime | float | str]:
        return iter(astuple(self))
```

However comparison is not as expected when inheriting from this class.

In example this class wouldn't compare according to the **eq** method in the ComparisonMixin:

```py
@dataclass
class Bloodsample(ComparisonMixin):
    datetime: datetime
    substance: str
    value: float
    category: Optional[str] = None
```

This is supposed to evaluate to true, but it evaluates to false:

```py
sample = Bloodsample(datetime(2024, 1, 9), "hemoglobin", 9.5, "hematology")
sample_with_none_value = Bloodsample(datetime(2024, 1, 9), "hemoglobin", 9.5, None)
assert sample == sample_with_none_value
# Raises AssertionError
```

I suspect that the MRO is wrong, but there is no `__mro__` attribute in the dataclasses. If implemented directly in the subclass the comparison works as expected.

What is the best way to implement this with dataclasses?

I tried manually ignoring comparison methods by setting `eq=False` in the dataclass decorator on subclasses. This works but it just feels wrong, so I want to hear if there is a better solution.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] showing how you're creating the subclasses and comparing them.

Comment: Aside: in the loop, you can `return False` as soon as `result is False`.

Comment: I have added an example subclass and an example comparison. 
And yeah thank you! That makes sense!

Comment: *Why* would you expect this mixin to allow `"hematology"` to compare as equal to `None`?  The only special behavior it gives is to allow inexact datetime matches.

Comment: `object` isn't an iterable type, so isn't a valid type hint for a value you assume will be iterable and useable with `zip`.

Comment: @jasonharper: It might be a weird implementation, but it is used to find a target bloodsample on a search. I want to find a match by an arbitrary number of parameters. So you could create a template (Bloodsample(None, "hemoglobin", None, None)) and match with all the actual data that has hemoglobin as substance and ignore the category, value and date. Or add date and ignore the rest and so on.

Comment: @chepner: I know, but Mypy does not like any other type annotation for __eq__ method, because it violates Liskov substitution principle. The actual implementation contains:
```python
...
    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(__o, ComparisonMixin):
            return NotImplemented
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `datclasses.dataclass` code generator *will create an `__eq__` which overrides the `__eq__` from your mixin*. So if you want to prevent that, you can tell the decorator not to generate an `__eq__` by using the appropriate argument to the decorator:

```
@dataclass(eq=False)
class Bloodsample(ComparisonMixin):
    datetime: datetime
    substance: str
    value: float
    category: Optional[str] = None
```

Remember, `dataclasses` is a *code generator*. By decorating your class with it, you are *telling it to generate an `__eq__` method for that class*.

Consider:

```
import dataclasses

class Foo:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("in my custom __eq__")
        return True

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Bar(Foo):
    x: int
    y: int

@dataclasses.dataclass(eq=False)
class Baz(Foo):
    x: int
    y: int

print("Testing Bar")
print(Bar(1,2) == Bar(1, 3))
print("Testing Baz")
print(Baz(1,2) == Baz(1, 3))
```

The above prints:

```
Testing Bar
False
Testing Baz
in my custom __eq__
True
```